# fetching data of joining tables in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

can you please tell me what's wrong with my function

```html
public function get_by(){
  $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('filiere');
        $this->db->join('module', 'module.code_filiere = filiere.code_filiere');
        $query = $this->db->get();
 }
```

I wanna display Two tables in one table using the foriegn key (code_filiere)

Comment: the only thing which is wrong is the lack of information ...

Comment: Soryy for not being clear enough what i wanted to say is that i have two tables filiere(code_filiere ,nom_filiere,departement) and module(code_module,nom_module,code_filiere) as you see code_filiere is a foreign key  I want to diplay the two tables in one using Datatables with codeigniter .

Comment: Can you post your controller method and view codes?

Comment: check my omments bellow please

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : You need to return data for controller

```
public function get_by(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('filiere');
    $this->db->join('module', 'module.code_filiere = filiere.code_filiere');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In the controller

```
$data = $this->your_model->get_by();
```

Solution 2 : You need to return data for controller

```
public function get_by(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('filiere');
    $this->db->join('module', 'module.code_filiere = filiere.code_filiere');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

In the controller

```
$data = $this->your_model->get_by()->result();
```

[From the doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data)

Answer (score 0):

nothing wrong in your function, but you didn't return the captured value from the function to the controller.

You should use

`$query->result()` for multi-value

OR

`$query->row()` for single value

from database

update your function

```
public function get_by(){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('filiere');
    $this->db->join('module', 'module.code_filiere = filiere.code_filiere');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : false;
}
```